# Different values while extracting from Google analytics core reporting API

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

When extracting for a single day results are accurate but extracting for a range inclusive of that date gives a different data set:

> data for 2017-05-08 gives 300

while

> data for 2017-05-08 to 2017-05-12 gives [294,376,500,250]

Please explain why is there a difference in the numbers extracted through these two methods

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact request.

Comment: using the google analytics query explorer

Comment: and?  you can Link the request you have made in query explorer

Comment: This was because as the date range increases the google analytics removes the duplicate visits within the range and returns only the unique visits on that day. This means that multiple visits by the same user within that date range would only be counted as one

Answer (score 0):

This was because as the date range increases the google analytics removes the duplicate visits within the range and returns only the unique visits on that day.

This means that multiple visits by the same user within that date range would only be counted as one.